# MariaDB Docker lagre db/binlog.* files. Overflows the disk to the point of failure

Tags: docker, mariadb, docker-compose, nextcloud, df

How to Fix?

**ls -lh /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.***

```
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 960M Aug 25 22:55 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000043
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 5.5M Aug 25 23:52 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000044
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 156M Aug 26 23:40 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000045
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 260M Aug 28 15:10 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000046
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 548M Sep  1 00:03 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000047
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 593M Sep  4 11:28 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000048
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999  13M Sep  4 13:21 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000049
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999 529M Sep  9 22:20 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.000050
-rw-rw---- 1 999 999  128 Sep  4 13:26 /root/docker/yml/nextcloud/db/binlog.index
```

**Docker compose yml DB PART**

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: nextcloudDB
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --log-bin=binlog --binlog-format=ROW --expire_logs_days=2
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=d`X'1B7Ss/=E;JxROOT
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=d`X'3B7SD/dE;Jx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    logging:
            driver: "json-file"
            options:
                max-size: "50m"
                max-file: "10"
```

**- ./db:/var/lib/mysql     special add ./ in ./db for backup**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary logs are used for data recovery, replication and database monitoring. And you can clear old ones. and quoting this answer from [DB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41054/270449)

> You need to let mysqld do that for you. Here is how mysqld manages it:
>
> The file mysql-bin.[index] keeps a list of all binary logs mysqld has
> generated and auto-rotated. The mechanisms for cleaning out the
> binlogs in conjunction with mysql-bin.[index] are:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'binlogname';
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE 'datetimestamp';
```

Comment: how send this command to docker maria db?

for example:
docker exec mariadb PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE (NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR);
tell me please

Comment: @dr.ipkins, contact with client and exec in it

Comment: mysqladmin --user=*** --password=*** --execute='PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR;'
not work

Comment: @dr.ipkins, if you run this from your PC you should add hostname/IP of the container. And better just define previous day

Answer (score 0):

The [Using and Maintaining the Binary Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-and-maintaining-the-binary-log/) page on the MariaDB Knowledgebase has the information on how to purge binary logs.

> To delete all binary log files on the server, run the [RESET MASTER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reset-master/) command. To delete all binary logs before a certain datetime, or up to a certain number, use [PURGE BINARY LOGS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-commands-purge-logs/).

The page also explains how to deal with the binlog retention automatically.

> Log files can also be removed automatically with the [expire_logs_days](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#expire_logs_days) system variable. This is set to 0 by default (no removal), but can be set to a time, in days, after which a binary log file will be automatically removed. Log files will only be checked for being older than expire_logs_days upon log rotation, so if your binary log only fills up slowly and does not reach [max_binlog_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#max_binlog_size) on a daily basis, you may see older log files still being kept. You can also force log rotation, and so expiry deletes, by running [FLUSH BINARY LOGS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flush/) on a regular basis. Always set expire_logs_days higher than any possible replica lag.

In your case lowering `max_binlog_size` should help the binlog rotations happen more frequently which in turn will reduce the amount of data that's being kept. If you add `--max_binlog_size=100M` to the `command` in your `docker-compose.yml`, the MariaDB server will flush the binary logs once they have exceeded 100MiB.

As mentioned by the documentation, you can manually run the `FLUSH BINARY LOGS` command to force a binlog rotation to take place which in turn will trigger the purging of old files.